# Converting string element into float problem

Tags: selenium, webdriver

Firstly, I have written a code to append data from `www.coinmarketcap.com` and I did it though. I repeatedly receive data. But it comes with `str` type. Then I tried to convert it into `float` but it did not work. The data I received has the form `2,179.87` How can I solve this problem? Thanks in advance!

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
values = []
counter = 0 

website = driver.get("https://www.binance.com/en/trade/ETH_USDT?theme=dark&type=spot")

while True:
    currency = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="__APP"]/div/div/div[4]/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[1]')
    print(currency.text)
    values.append(float(currency.text))
    time.sleep(0.1)
    counter += 1
    if counter == 300:
        break

time.sleep(1)
```

In the part `values.append(float(currency.text))` I got an error called:

```
could not convert string to float: '2,184.65'
```

As I mentioned above I cannot convert this string.

Comment: Please show us your code and the errors you receiving

Answer (score 0):

See this string `2,179.87` has `,` in it. So you have to first replace that like this `replace(',' , '')` and then simply convert to float using `float()`

```
a = "2,184.65"

print(type(a))

b = a.replace(',' , '')
c = float(b)

print(type(c))

print(c)
```

for you specific issue, I think :

```
values.append(float(currency.text.replace(',' , '')))
```